# Recalculate normals with modifier in v. 2.83?

Tags: modifiers

BH

I have a whole system of boolean operators and array modifiers etc and I would like to do everything with just modifiers, as oppose to edit tools

When making a cut into a mesh using the difference boolean operator, almost always the normals are messed up, I want them to all be calculated outside always, but sometimes that is changed with the modifier, which is a problem because I later want to combine it to another mesh using the union modifier, but it doesn't always work if the normals are messed up

In general I could still apply the modifier then in edit mode manually recalculate to outside using the shortcut, but I don't want to apply the modifier since I want to keep everything dynamic and editable

I found the Normal Edit modifier but I haven't been able to find any information on if it's possible to use it to recalculate the normals to the outside using it, or any other modifier

Any ideas?

Blend file, everything is being added to a "union" after it's own various boolean modifiers, but when its exported as a GLB many faces seem to be flipped, with no specifc way to tell what's causing it, it would be nice to just recalculate everything outside:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Flip faces" operator in geometry nodes to, well, flip the normals of selected faces.

[image]

Here, I'm creating the Boolean difference with a cube, and then flipping the faces of faces that are within 0.001 units of that cube, which should be only the faces that were created by the boolean operation.  On the material with backface culling enabled, these faces then remain invisible in a material preview.

Note that there's something funky with the mesh display of face orientation for geometry nodes Booleans.  At the created faces, there's some z-fighting of blue and red (normals pointing both ways) but this seems particular to the face orientation code, not the GN boolean.  My tests with GN Boolean differences haven't had any problems with the direction of the faces outside of this artifact of that one display mode.  However, if you decide you want to flip your faces, regardless of reason, the above is how you do it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Sometimes when making a cut the other normals, besides for the ones that the cut was made to, get turned inside out, is the a genetic way to make all faces recalculate outside? I'm also using an older version of blender that doesn't have geometry nodes (2.83)

Comment: You might want to specify what version of Blender you're using in the question.  I know of no way to flip normals with a modifier outside of geometry nodes.

Comment: I didnt see in the TOS that one has to add the version number to the question, but done.